# ruby should I use self. or @

Tags: ruby

Here is my ruby code

```
class Demo
  attr_accessor :lines

  def initialize(lines)
    self.lines = lines
  end
end
```

In the above code I could have used

```
    @lines = lines
```

Mostly I see people using @ in initialize method. Is there a preferred way of doing among these two and why?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

When you use `@lines`, you are accessing the instance variable itself. `self.lines` actually goes through the `lines` method of the class; likewise, `self.lines = x` goes through the `lines=` method. So use `@` when you want to access the variable directly, and `self.` when you want to access via the method.

To directly answer your question, normally you want to set the instance variables directly in your `initialize` method, but it depends on your use-case.

Comment: I consider it somewhat of a stylistic choice as long as the getters are only returning the value of the variable. If there is some massaging needed before the variable is used, then it becomes important to use the getter method, but mostly for DRY reasons.

Comment: @the Tin Man: Is the question asking about setters rather than getters?

Comment: `attr_accessor` generates both setters and getters. I'm commenting about getters. The same concern whether to use `@` or `self` applies in both, as does whether to use the autogenerated versions vs. declaring a method to set/get.

Answer (score 5):

`self.lines` is a method, `@lines` is the instance variable. In your constructor you'll want to use self.lines I would argue, but that's up for debate. It's just a stylistic difference, really. If you want a deeper discussion of direct vs. indirect variable access, read the chapter from Kent Beck's Smalltalk Best Practice Patterns.

Answer (score 2):

The main difference would be if you redefined `lines=` to do something other than `@lines = lines`.

For example, you could add validation to the attribute (for example, raising if `lines` is empty).

Answer (score 2):

I think there is a little difference that has not be mentioned yet. The instance variable @lines can only be accessed within the class.

```
class Foo
 def initialize
   @lines = 1
 end
end

foo = Foo.new
foo.lines
>> NoMethodError: undefined method `lines' for #<Foo:0x1017cfb80 @lines=0>
foo.send(:lines)
>> 1
```

If you define attr_accessor :lines all instances of that class can access the lines variable:

```
class Foo
 attr_accessor :lines
 def initialize
   self.lines = 1
 end
end

foo = Foo.new
foo.lines
>> 1
```

If you want your variable to be accessible for all instances you should use attr_accessor.

Comment: `@lines` can certainly be accessed outside of the instance, but not as conveniently (`foo.instance_variable_get(:@lines)`).