# What convention should I use for instance variables?

Tags: ruby

Is there any instance variable convention used in Ruby code? Namely, I noticed that, in the examples section, instance variable are initialized using the '@' and then the code uses a variable name without the '@':

```
class BookInStock
  attr_reader: isbn
  attr_accessor: price

  def initialize (isbn, price)
    @isbn = isbn
    @price = Float (price)
  end

  def price_in_cents
    Integer (price * 100 + 0.5)
  end
end
```

And there are examples where the code, the instance variable is used all the time with the prefix '@'

```
class BookStock

  def set_price (price)
    @price = price
  end

  def get_price
    @price
  end
end
```

What is the difference these records? When should I use '@' only in the initialization of an object and when in all the class methods?

Comment: possible duplicate of [ruby should I use self. or @](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5275749/ruby-should-i-use-self-or)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can only use the instance variable name without `@` if you have defined an attribute reader for this variable (with `attr_reader` or `attr_accessor`). This is a lightweight helper to create a method that returns the instance variable's value.

The difference is a question between using the **public interface** of your class or accessing **private data**. It is recommended to use the public interface in subclasses or included modules, for example. This ensures encapsulation. So you should not access instance variables from within subclasses or modules.

In the class itself, ask yourself this question: if the implementation of the attribute changes, should my usage the attribute change as well? If the answer is **yes**, use the instance variable directly; if it's **no**, use the public attribute.

An example. Suppose we have a `Person` class that represents a person and should contain that person's name. First there is this version, with only a simple `name` attribute:

```
class Person
  attr_reader :name

  def initialize(name)
    @name = name
  end

  def blank?
    !@name
  end

  def to_s
    name
  end
end
```

Note how we use the **instance variable** for the `blank?` method, but the **public attribute** for the `to_s` method. This is intentional!

Let's say that in a refactoring step we decide that the `Person` class should keep track of a `first_name` and `last_name` seperately.

```
class Person
  def initialize(first_name, last_name)
    @first_name, @last_name = first_name, last_name
  end

  def name
    "#{@first_name} #{@last_name}"
  end

  def blank?
    !@first_name and !@last_name
  end

  def to_s
    name
  end
end
```

We now change the `name` attribute to a regular method, which composes the name from a person's first and last name. We can now see that it is possible to keep the same implementation for `to_s`. However, `blank?` needs to be changed because it was dependent on the underlying data. This is the reason why `to_s` used the *attribute*, but `blank?` used the *instance variable*.

Of course, the distinction is not always easy to make. When in doubt, choose the public API over accessing private data.

Answer (score 6):

In your first example, `@price` is an instance variable.

In the method definition for `price_in_cents`, `price` is actually a method call to `price()`.  Because of Ruby's syntactic sugar, `()` is omitted.

It looks like there's no explicit definition for `price()`, but `attr_accessor :price` defined both `price()` and `price=(value)` a.k.a. getter and setter. You can try to comment out the `attr_accessor :price` line, you will get an "undefined local variable or method" exception when the `BookInStock`'s instance calls `price_in_cents`.

An instance variable is always have an `@` prefix. If no accessor methods defined, you can not use that name without `@` prefix.

Comment: Nice answer, I have some small nitpicks though: `price=()` should be `price=(value)` and the final bit about the class definition is a bit unclear.

Comment: Modified a bit according to your advice. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Using `name = value` is an error, because that creates a local variable named `name`. You must use `self.name = value`.

As for convention, you can only get away with using `@name` if you can guarantee that the accessors will always be lightweight attr_accessors. In all other cases, using `@name` over `self.name` will violate encapsulation and give yourself a headache. You gave the exact reason in your question — if there is extra logic in the getter/setter, you must duplicate it if you access the instance variable directly.