# Ruby instance variable syntax convention

Tags: ruby, coding-style, syntax

What's the Ruby convention for referring to instance variables inside an instance method?

Consider the following variations:

```
def MyClass
    attr_accessor :q

    def initialize(z)
        @q = z
    end

    def method_one
        puts q
    end

    def method_two
        puts @q
    end

    def method_three
        puts self.q
    end
end
```

Which convention `q`, `@q` or `self.q` is preferred?

Comment: Similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5275749/ruby-should-i-use-self-or/5293342#5293342

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The whole reason that Ruby uses instance variables and accessor methods (with syntax sugar to *look* like you're getting direct access to properties) is so that you can refactor your classes and external consumers of your interface

```
puts musicObj.minutes
```

don't have to know if you internally have:

```
attr_accessor :minutes
```

or

```
def minutes
  @seconds / 60.0
end
```

This same rational applies equally well to your own code. If you have a class with 100 methods that all reference your `@minutes`, and then you decide that you really should be storing `@seconds` you will need to change 100 methods. On the other hand, if you had used `minutes` (your "method_one") instead, none of your methods would need to change.

There is a small performance hit for using the method-invocation notation instead of directly accessing the instance variable. If speed is *critical* you may want to consider direct access; otherwise, I encourage you to eat your own dog food and use any publicly-accessible interfaces you expose, when they exist.

*And, as @Alex answered, you must use the `self.foo = 42` notation when invoking a 'setter' method, as `foo = 42` will always set a local variable instead.*

Comment: Good point (+1). But your example sucks a bit. If you only use the accessors, `self.minutes=` in your example will just store seconds with a resolution of 60 :-)

Comment: @undur_gongor Not if you pass in a float number of minutes; e.g. `def minutes=(m); @seconds = (m*60).round; end`

Answer (score 3):

`self.q` is used when setting the variable

```
self.q = 'Some value.'
```

whereas `q` is used when getting the variable

```
puts q
do_something_with_variable(q)
```

Of course, these are purely conventions. You can substitute `self.q` for `q` when *getting* the variable whenever you like (although consistency is recommended).

I find [this discussion](http://railsforum.com/viewtopic.php?id=23155) quite enlightening with regards to using `@q`.

Comment: `@q` seems to work when setting the variable in `initialize`. Is `self.q` required?

Comment: @MrMusic: `@q` works for setting too. After all, that's the instance variable itself.